# How to create a Automator service to compress a file in gzip or bzip format when clicking mouse's right button over a folder or file?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

Does anyone have a script to use on Automator service to compress a file, files, a folder or folders when clicking the right mouse button? It would be an alternative option for the Compress option, that compress to zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the service template and use a shell script like this:

```
n=$1
[[ -e $n.tgz ]] && { i=2; n="$1-$i"; }
while [[ -e $n.tgz ]]; do n="${n%-*}-$((i++))"; done
d=${1%/*}
cd -- "$d"
COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar -czf "$n.tgz" -- "${@#"$d/"}"
```

[image]

Change -z to -j and tgz to tbz to use bzip2.

The service should usually be used with a single folder as input. If the input is multiple files, it doesn't create a containing directory for the files.

Setting COPYFILE_DISABLE tells tar to remove extended attributes and ACLs instead of using the AppleDouble format:

```
$ touch a;xattr -w key value a
$ tar -cf a.tar a;tar -tf a.tar
./._a
a
$ COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar -cf a2.tar a;tar -tf a2.tar
a
$
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. It works for me only inside automator.

Comment: That might be because it expects the arguments to be absolute paths. If you are creating an archive from the shell, you might use an alias like `alias tarc='COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar --exclude .DS_Store -c'` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but should I replace the COPYFILE_DISABLE line or create an alias in the system?

Comment: @tenshimsm I meant like add that line to your ~/.bash_profile and then run `tarc -zf directory.tgz directory` in a terminal.